# Android Google Maps API v2 маркеры

Tags: android, google-maps-api, java

Есть карта, на которую ставятся маркеры из БД. Но появляются они на ней, только после срабатывания `onResume()` в активности. Ниже метод, который расставляет маркеры.

```
    public void place(){

      for (int i = 0; i<user_sex.length; i++){
            //someone = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(xx[i], yy[i])).title("Вы здесь!");
            if (user_sex[i]==1){

            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name[i]).position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ROSE)));
            list.put(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i]), i);

            }
            if (user_sex[i]==2){
                //m[i]=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Посмотреть").position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name[i]).position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN)));
                list.put(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i]), i);
            }else{
                if(xx[i]!=0 && yy[i]!=0 && (user_sex[i] < 1)){
                    //m[i]=map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title("Посмотреть").position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
                map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(name[i]).position(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i])).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_YELLOW)));
                list.put(new LatLng(xx[i],yy[i]), i);
                }
                }
            //map.addMarker(someone);
        }
  }
```

А вот в этом случае я могу их видеть без перезагрузки активности:

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(x,y)).zoom(16).build();
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    place();
    this.onResume();
```

Но это решение не позволяет зумить карту и перемещать камеру. Есть решение моей проблемы? Вот мой метод `onResume()`:

```
@Override
  protected void onResume(){
      super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
            1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10,
            locationListener);
        checkEnabled();
  }
```

Comment: а покажите где именно вы добавляете их, где вызывается метод place()

Comment: @Andreich во втором боксе кода видно, где вызывается place(). Все эти методы находятся в одном классе MapActivity. Т.е. получается, что place() вызывается в методе onCreate() самой активности.

Comment: @Andreich Помогите мне, пожалуйста!

Comment: Весь код покажите.